# Append to Spotify playlist

Tags: javascript, api, spotify, spotify-app

API v1, Spotify v 0.9.4.185

I don't seem to be able to append songs to a playlist.

This works:

```
playlist.tracks.insert(playlist_tracks.ref(playlist_tracks.length-1), tracks_to_append)
```

This doesn't:

```
playlist.tracks.insert(playlist_tracks.ref(playlist_tracks.length), tracks_to_append)
```

fail callback for the latter says " is not a track URI." in err.message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on the documentation, my code should work.  However, I overlooked the add method of Collection.  Thanks to ocip on irc.